# How can I change the way my data shows up on GridView after I pulled it from SQL DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview

I pull the data out of my database and put it in a DataSet through SqlAdapted and then DataBind it.

My question is how can I change the way data is presented in the table?

Example: Some should have 2 digits after decimal and some should have 3 etc.
Example: Some should be right justified whereas some should be centered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you build your Gridview, you can assign items as `<asp:BoundFields>`, instead of using "AutoGenerateColumns". This gives you more control, for example:

`<asp:BoundField DataField="DateLastContacted" HeaderText="Contacted" SortExpression="DateLastContacted" ItemStyle-CssClass="resultscell" HeaderStyle-CssClass="resultsheader"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" DataFormatString="{0:dd MMM yyy}" NullDisplayText="N/A" />`

You can use `ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center"` for your alignment, and use `DataFormatString="{0:N2}"` to specify decimals, see here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx

HTH